# CreateThread() // GetLastError() returns 87

Tags: c++, multithreading

Below is a simple program that creates a thread.  I hope I am missing something obvious. FYI - I am a newb to Win32.

Why does GetLastError() in the thread execution return 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

long WINAPI Run();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  DWORD id;

  HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Run, NULL, 0, &id);    

  // hThread is not NULL  

  DWORD err = GetLastError(); // returns 0

  int input;
  std::cin  >> input;

  return 0;
}

long WINAPI Run() 
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError(); // returns 87
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really use a callback function with the right signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetLastError()` function only returns valid results when it is called *immediately after* a Win32 API function that returns a "failed" result.

In your case, you are calling `GetLastError()` as the first thing in a new thread, which is definitely not immediately after a Win32 API function call.

Also, each thread has its own copy of a "last error" so they don't step on each other.

Comment: Hmm. That is good to know. However when I do call a Win32 function e.g. GetQueuedCompletionStatus(...). It returns true and then if I call GetLastError() it returns 87.  If I call SetLastError(0) before GetQueuedCompletionStatus(...) GetLastError() returns 0 post the call.  This is why I am confused as it appears to GetQueuedCompletionStatus() doesn't set the "last error" to 0 or something else valid if it  succeeds. So am I right that I should check for false, then call GetLastError()?

Comment: That's right; if an API function succeeds then it usually doesn't set the last error value (there are exceptions; see the documentation for the API function for details).

Comment: A call to `GetLastError()` only has a defined result if either the most recent Win32 API call failed, if it's documented to set the error on success, or if you called `SetLastError()` yourself after the most recent Win32 API call.